# RichEdit and WM_VSCROLL message

Tags: delphi, windows-7, delphi-xe2, richedit

When number of lines is not too large no problem with WM_VSCROLL message. When RichEdit has large number of lines (in my case ~130K lines with average 150 chars) it not works.
`RichEdit1.Perform(WM_VSCROLL, MakeWParam(SB_THUMBPOSITION, N), 0);` scroll to top (N > 5) or more than it should (N <= 5). Can I do vertical scroll in other way ?

P.s.
For testing can be used [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2822471/delphi-center-specific-line-in-trichedit-by-scrolling) written by Sertac Akyuz.

Comment: Does the problem stay consistent when the file doesn't change?  In other words, does the code produce inconsistent results or do you consistently get the same wrong results?

Comment: @SilentD Yes, always the same, reproducible.

Comment: Scrolling is not the only problem with that code with that many lines. The code uses `EM_POSFROMCHAR` to retrieve the position of a line. `EM_POSFROMCHAR` returns the vertical position in the high-order *word*, which can refer at most to MaxWord (65535).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't think of a way to adapt the code linked in the question to be able to work with rich edit version 2.0 for the reason I mentioned in the comment to the question. But luckily it might not be necessary..

For Windows XP SP1 and later rich edit version 3.0 is included with the OS. See '[About Rich Edit Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787873%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)' on MSDN. You don't have to do anything to use version 3.0, the class names of version 2.0 and 3.0 are the same. If a version 3.0 'riched20.dll' is deployed on the system, the VCL gets to use it.

Interestingly there is no problem with [`WM_VSCROLL`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787873%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). The message still use a word sized scroll position, but the rich edit control adapts itself: you get a scroll range of at most 65535.

About the problem with [`EM_POSFROMCHAR`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb761631%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), with a version 3.0 rich edit control, if you pass a pointer to a `POINTL` in wParam, the control detects it and instead of returning the coordinates, it fills in the parameter.

So, here is a sample having slightly modified version of the same code (please add error/special case handling as appropriate) (works only with `WordWrap` set to false):

```
const
  Line = 'The SCROLLINFO structure contains scroll bar parameters...'#13#10;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: Integer;
  s: string;
begin
  s := '';
  for i := 1 to 130000 do
    s := s + IntToStr(i) + ' - ' + Line;
  SendMessage(RichEdit1.Handle, WM_SETTEXT, 0, LPARAM(PChar(s)));
end;

procedure VertCenterLine(RichEdit: TRichEdit; LineNum: Integer);
var
  LineIndex, MaxLineIndex: lResult;
  LinePos, MaxPos: TPoint;
  ScrollInfo: TScrollInfo;
  ScrollPos: Extended;
begin
  SendMessage(RichEdit.Handle, EM_SETSEL, 0, 0);
  SendMessage(RichEdit.Handle, winapi.messages.EM_SCROLLCARET, 0, 0);
  RichEdit.SetFocus;

  LineIndex := SendMessage(RichEdit.Handle, EM_LINEINDEX, LineNum, 0);
  MaxLineIndex := SendMessage(RichEdit.Handle, EM_LINEINDEX,
      RichEdit.Lines.Count, 0);   // to account for possible line feed at end
  if MaxLineIndex = -1 then
    MaxLineIndex := SendMessage(RichEdit.Handle, EM_LINEINDEX,
        RichEdit.Lines.Count - 1, 0);

  SendMessage(RichEdit.Handle, EM_POSFROMCHAR, WPARAM(@LinePos), LineIndex);
  SendMessage(RichEdit.Handle, EM_POSFROMCHAR, WPARAM(@MaxPos), MaxLineIndex);

  ScrollInfo.cbSize := SizeOf(ScrollInfo);
  ScrollInfo.fMask := SIF_RANGE;
  GetScrollInfo(RichEdit.Handle, SB_VERT, ScrollInfo);

  ScrollPos := (LinePos.y - RichEdit.ClientHeight / 2) / MaxPos.y;
  ScrollPos := ScrollPos * (ScrollInfo.nMax - ScrollInfo.nMin);
  SendMessage(RichEdit.Handle, WM_VSCROLL,
                            MakeWParam(SB_THUMBPOSITION, Round(ScrollPos)), 0);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  VertCenterLine(RichEdit1, 110000);
end;
```

Comment: Thank you, it works!! When I asked the question I was hoping that you will see it :)

Comment: @Branko - You're welcome! I made a little change to the code so that now it does not have to scroll to top and receive focus.